# How do you move a sinatra app to github pages?

Tags: ruby, heroku, web, github, sinatra

I created a sinatra app and I'm trying to put it on github pages. I can run my app on localhost, but I don't know how to push it to the actual web.

I have tried googling and searching stackoverflow and I keep seeing people use heroku. Is this required? Is there anyway to push directly from sinatra to the web? I can get a simple index.html file to run on github pages, but I don't know how to get my sinatra app to run. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

As Sirajus says, Github pages only serve static HTML pages. Sinatra is a framework for producing code that produces web pages. It's really there for sites that require some server side processing (i.e. *dynamic*), but [can serve static pages too](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Static%20Files) (a wise decision).

It doesn't serve the pages itself, it runs on a [Rack](https://rack.github.io/) compliant [application server](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_servers) (like Thin, Puma, Unicorn or Webrick) and when asked, it builds the page, gives it to the server and the server gives it to you.

Entirely static sites like Github pages or those served via Amazon's S3 are just a collection of HTML files sitting behind HTTP file servers (those of the Apache and Nginx variety). They're *static* because they're not generated on the fly… *dynamically*. They don't change, there's no extra processing needed to serve them. They're just sat there wait to be served. You could use things like Sinatra and Thin to do this, but the added complexity adds maintenance work, security issues, costs extra money, time… and crucially, slows the serving speed down. If your site is essentially all static, by which I mean there's no need for the server to process anything, then you may be better off using something that generates static pages from the off. [There are many libraries to help with this](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation), Middleman (based on Padrino and hence Sinatra) and Jekyll come to mind, as does Nanoc.

You can emulate what these libraries do by saving the output of each route and uploading that, *if* it's appropriate. There are libraries that help with this, like [Sinatra Static](https://github.com/paulasmuth/sinatra-static) and its fork, [Sinatra Export](https://github.com/hooktstudios/sinatra-export). You could use cURL to save the pages with a command *like* `curl http://localhost:9292/ > index.html` for every single path if you wanted. I did something like this for my own blog the other day.

If it's not appropriate to do this or you can't be bothered, set up some server hosting. A lot of these services are free to start with so it won't hurt to give them all a try, you'll learn a lot from doing each.

Answer (score 2):

To run your sinatra app you need to host it with a server. Github pages only run html page not a ruby web application.

To host your sinatra app you can use heroku/ digital ocean.

Comment: If I used something like amazon's aws does that allow ruby application? Also which do you recommend?

Comment: Heroku is free for few web application and also AWS is free for one year. And digital ocean is paid service. heroku as you are beginer.